# Redirect to another controller after ajax call

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to redirect to another controller after a successful ajax call also i want to send some data that I get in the response

User Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/user/preferences")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, List<String>> userPreferences(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String , List<String>> finalPlaces = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
    finalPlaces.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<String>(topPlaces));
    return finalPlaces; 
}
```

Ajax Call

```
$(".savebutton").click(function(){
     $.ajax({       
        url: "<c:url value='/user/preferences' />",
        type: 'POST',            
        data:{  
        preferences : preferences
        },
        success: function(response) 
        {
        }, 
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert('Error');
         }
   });
});
```

when the above ajax call returns successfully I want to call a method of another controller

Places Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/places")
public ModelAndView showRecommnededPlaces(Map<String, List<String>> recommndedPlaces) {
    System.out.print(recommndedPlaces);     
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("places");
    return model; 
}
```

is it possible to directly call the places controller action from the user controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can `return "redirect:/places";` in your user controller, like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/user/preferences")
public @ResponseBody String userPreferences(HttpServletRequest request) {

    Map< String, Integer> userPreferences = new HashMap< String, Integer>();
    . 
    . 
    .
    return "redirect:/places"; 
}
```

Comment: If I change the return type of userPreferences to a Map , then how can I redirect to places and passing the map as argument

Comment: I am not sure if I am following you, but you are aware of the Model object on the springframework? `org.springframework.ui.Model`

Comment: Yeah I am , if you see in the userPreferences method I make a map finalPlaces once the request is successful I want to send this map to the places Controller getRecommendedPlaces action.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay about putting dependency from one controller to the next, you can actually do this:

```
public class UserController {
    @Autowired PreferencesController prefController;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/user/preferences")
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, List<String>> userPreferences(HttpServletRequest request)         {
        Map<String , List<String>> finalPlaces = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        finalPlaces.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<String>(topPlaces));
        return prefController. showRecommendedPlaces(finalPlaces); 
    }
}
```

Not saying this is good - since you will have to match the response type of your called controller appropriately, but nevertheless an approach